# Is there a quota limitation for deferred tasks

Tags: google-app-engine, task, deferred, quota

I have written some deferred tasks and deployed on the GAE. I can exceute them, till a certain amount. And then I just can't start another deferred task. I have to wait for a week, till I can start the next one. The task is writing some data to ther datastore.

Does someone know if there is a hidden quota limitation for deferred tasks? Because, I can't see that any of my quotas is exceeded. And on my budget from billing status has no fee.

Comment: What error do you get when you try?

Comment: There is no error. My first entry in the method is a log-statement and not even that is printed. The strange thing is, that if I start the task a week later it runs through like there would be no problem at all. Thats why I thought there must be some kind of a hidden quota.